# Does the body tag have some style rule that controls other elements?

Tags: css, styling

This is the HTML structure I have

```
<html>
   <head>
      <style></style>
      <title></title>
   </head>
   <header></header>
   <nav></nav>
   <body></body>
   <footer></footer>
</html>
```

And this is the style

```
html{
    height:99%;
    width: 99%;
    position:absolute;} 

header{
    position:absolute;
    top:0%;     left:0%;
    width:100%; height:7%;}

nav{
    position:absolute;
    top:7%;    left:0%;
    width:10%; height:85%;}

body{
    position:absolute;
    top:0%;    left:0%;
    width:90%; height:90%;}

footer{
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;  left:0%;
    height:5%; width:100%;}
```

*I did have borders and background colors to identify elements on page, but omitted for brevity.*

I want it to look like below, **with every element being set (positioned) relative to the html tag**. But when I position the body, all the other things move with it. Even though they are not children of the tag.

```
 ------------------------------
|           Header            |
|¯¯¯¯|¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯|
|    |                        |
|Nav |                        |
|    |       Body             |
|    |                        |
|____|________________________|
|            Footer           |
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
```

Comment: I suggest you read [MDN's introduction to HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Introduction).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`<html>` element may only contain `<head>` and `<body>` elements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-html-element)*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

All elements used for presentation belong within the `<body>` element:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Example</h1>
    </header>
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <address>
        Some location
      </address>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

The reason everything is moving relative to the `<body>` element, is that an [implicit `<body>` element is being created immediately after your `<head>` element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#optional-tags) to contain the structural elements.

<sub>* assuming HTML5</sub>

Comment: Oh thanks, I thought I could get creative by putting elements before  <body>